# Assign a different ip for each .ovpn client? OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

Alright, so I'm using OpenVPN on ubuntu 14.04.
Say I have a box, with 5 IPs, I have openvpn, but I want to make 5 different client certificates and .ovpn files, but each of those certificates will have a different ip, so client1 will have the first ip, client2 will have the second IP, and so forth, or some kind of method that makes SURE that each client gets their OWN IP address out of the 5 and that no two clients are going to be using the same IP address. The IPs I have right now to use are

```
198.251.80.134 198.251.80.136 209.141.38.87 198.251.80.131 209.141.38.94
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Route the internals to an external through the respective NAT

Answer (score 1):

This applies to a routed network, not bridged (otherwise just configure the DHCP server).

You should use the `client-config-dir` option on the server. You have to supply a directory that has a per-client configuration file. The name of the file should be the same as the name of the certificate (ie. the name of the certificate supplied to easy-rsa). Then you can specify options to be used for each client (you can think of it as a "static DHCP", though there are many other options that can be configured for a particular client, not just the IP address).

For example (you can use comments in those files):

```
#first is client address, second is netmask
ifconfig-push 172.16.183.3 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Would the 172.16.183.3 be the external ip?

Comment: No, it is the client IP inside the VPN.

Comment: How would I make that client IP go to a public external ip then?

Comment: Do you want to assign external public IP addresses to some VPN clients? Then you need to allocate them addresses from a private pool, assign all public addresses to the server and configure iptables forwarding to from public addresses to addresses within the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using /etc/openvpn/ipp.txt file

Basically you need to add (one line per client):

`certname,ip`

for example in my case i got:

`InfraTIC,10.8.1.4`